# File api :: Recieveing file name instead of browse,drag,droop

Tags: css, html, fileapi

I am using Html file Api to read a file.Using  i read it.it will show a browse button and select the file and read ..in this manner.

But instead of the above i want to manually set one default file to read every time.With out changing the code how can it possible.

In file Api it read the file from browser using ----

```
function resetFileUploader() {
   getElem("uploader").innerHTML= '<input id="filechooser" type="file" />'; 
    getElem("filechooser").addEventListener("change", getFile, false);
```

}

Comment: I really don't understand your question, and I don't see any other answers.  Perhaps you could try describing it another way and show your attempt to code it.

Comment: now you understand the ques